# Is it possible to get the SQL alias of a join table for a Order by using Hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria

I have this type of query

```
Critetria criteria = session.createCriteria(Perosn.class,"person");
criteria.createAlias("person.cityInformation","city",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("city.streetInformation","street",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
criteria.add(new NativeSQLOrder("field({alias}.id,3,2,1)",true)));
```

NativeSQLOrder.java

```
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.annotations.common.util.StringHelper;
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaQuery;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;

public class NativeSQLOrder extends Order
{
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
    private final static String PROPERTY_NAME       = "uselessAnyways";
    private boolean             ascending;
    private String              sql;

    protected NativeSQLOrder(String sql, boolean ascending)
    {
        super(PROPERTY_NAME, ascending);
        this.sql = sql;
        this.ascending = ascending;
    }

    @Override
    public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException
    {
        StringBuilder fragment = new StringBuilder();
        fragment.append("(");
        fragment.append(sql);
        fragment.append(")");
        fragment.append(ascending ? " asc" : " desc");
        return StringHelper.replace(sql, "{alias}", criteriaQuery.getSQLAlias(criteria));
    }
}
```

I want order by on id of street field but using this I am getting alias of first table **Person**.Is there any way that I will get **alias of Street** table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the CriteriaQuery only allows recovering the root table alias.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/CriteriaQuery.html#getSQLAlias%28org.hibernate.Criteria%29

Comment: I solved this.I have done modifications in my file. getColumnsUsingProjection of CriteriaQuery gives alias name for all which are used in our query.